# $S^1$ acting on $SO(n+1)/SO(n-1)$ by translations

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I'm ready right now in a paper, that $S^1$ acts on $SO(n+1)/SO(n-1)$ by right translations.

I thought that a Liegroup $G$ acting by right translations, means that we have a right action $\varphi \colon G \times G \to G, \ (g,h) \mapsto \varphi_g(h)$ with $\varphi_g \circ \varphi_h = \varphi_{hg}$.

But we have clearly, that $SO(n+1)/SO(n-1) \neq S^1$. So what do the author mean by "$S^1$ acts on $SO(n+1)/SO(n-1)$ by right translations"?

Edit: Maybe I should mention, that in this paper we get an action of $SO(n+1) \times S^1$, so that $S^1$ has to commute with the action of $SO(n+1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should refer to the fact that $SO(2)\times SO(n-1)$ naturally is a subgroup of $SO(n+1)$. Since this means that translations with respect to $SO(2)$ commute with translations with resprect to $SO(n-1)$, it provides a natural action of $SO(2)$ on  $SO(n+1)/SO(n-1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I forgot an important fact. Would this action commute with the natural action of $SO(n+1)$ on $SO(n+1)/SO(n-1)$?

Comment: Yes, it does, since right translations commute with left translations.

Comment: Ah yes, clearly you are right!